# Facebook iOS Login - Delegate methods not being called

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I'm trying to implement the Facebook login for one of my applications and the delegate methods - `fbDidLogin:` / `application: handleOpenURL:` / `fbDidNotLogin:` aren't being called. Here is the code that I'm using. Any help is much appreciated!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ... 
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kFacebookAppId];
}

-(IBAction) loginWithFacebook:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }
    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSArray* permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              @"email", nil] retain];
        [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Facebook delegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize]; 
}

-(void) fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled {

}

-(void) fbDidLogout {

}
```

I also have the Facebook App ID in the `info.plist` file under the appropriate entry. I have break points in the `loginWithFacebook:` method and they hit successfully. the `[facebook authorize:]` method gets called as well.

Thanks, 
Teja.

Comment: Did you make sure do set yourself as FBSessionDelegate ?

Comment: I think the `[facebook autorize:permissions delegate:self]` sets the session delegate. I've tried setting it using `[facebook setSessionDelegate:self]` as well, but I still have the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oops, I've just realized the `application: handleOpenURL:` method is an iOS application delegate method. I had it in one of my UIViewControllers. Moved it to the right place and it works.

Answer (score 0):

application: handleOpenURL: calls than also it doesn't calling delegate methods. what should be problem?